# Flask Lightsail logs receiving requests every 5 seconds

Tags: amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-lightsail

I've deployed a Flask application to Lightsail via a tutorial provided on the [AWS website](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/serve-a-flask-app/).

Everything is working as expected in terms of my frontend communicating with my backend, but as I try to debug and access the container logs via the Lightsail console, I notice that I'm currently receiving requests every 5 seconds. The logs look as follows:

```
[4/May/2022:06:48:30] 172.26.7.217 - - [04/May/2022 06:48:30] "[33mGET / HTTP/1.1[0m" 404 -
[4/May/2022:06:48:30] 172.26.17.192 - - [04/May/2022 06:48:30] "[33mGET / HTTP/1.1[0m" 404 -
[4/May/2022:06:48:35] 172.26.47.225 - - [04/May/2022 06:48:35] "[33mGET / HTTP/1.1[0m" 404 -
[4/May/2022:06:48:35] 172.26.57.133 - - [04/May/2022 06:48:35] "[33mGET / HTTP/1.1[0m" 404 -
[4/May/2022:06:48:35] 172.26.7.217 - - [04/May/2022 06:48:35] "[33mGET / HTTP/1.1[0m" 404 -
[4/May/2022:06:48:35] 172.26.17.192 - - [04/May/2022 06:48:35] "[33mGET / HTTP/1.1[0m" 404 -
[4/May/2022:06:48:40] 172.26.47.225 - - [04/May/2022 06:48:40] "[33mGET / HTTP/1.1[0m" 404 -
[4/May/2022:06:48:40] 172.26.57.133 - - [04/May/2022 06:48:40] "[33mGET / HTTP/1.1[0m" 404 -
[4/May/2022:06:48:40] 172.26.7.217 - - [04/May/2022 06:48:40] "[33mGET / HTTP/1.1[0m" 404 -
[4/May/2022:06:48:40] 172.26.17.192 - - [04/May/2022 06:48:40] "[33mGET / HTTP/1.1[0m" 404 -
[4/May/2022:06:48:45] 172.26.47.225 - - [04/May/2022 06:48:45] "[33mGET / HTTP/1.1[0m" 404 -
[4/May/2022:06:48:45] 172.26.57.133 - - [04/May/2022 06:48:45] "[33mGET / HTTP/1.1[0m" 404 -
[4/May/2022:06:48:45] 172.26.7.217 - - [04/May/2022 06:48:45] "[33mGET / HTTP/1.1[0m" 404 -
[4/May/2022:06:48:45] 172.26.17.192 - - [04/May/2022 06:48:45] "[33mGET / HTTP/1.1[0m" 404 -
[4/May/2022:06:48:50] 172.26.47.225 - - [04/May/2022 06:48:50] "[33mGET / HTTP/1.1[0m" 404 -
[4/May/2022:06:48:50] 172.26.57.133 - - [04/May/2022 06:48:50] "[33mGET / HTTP/1.1[0m" 404 -
[4/May/2022:06:48:50] 172.26.7.217 - - [04/May/2022 06:48:50] "[33mGET / HTTP/1.1[0m" 404 -
[4/May/2022:06:48:50] 172.26.17.192 - - [04/May/2022 06:48:50] "[33mGET / HTTP/1.1[0m" 404 -
[4/May/2022:06:48:55] 172.26.47.225 - - [04/May/2022 06:48:55] "[33mGET / HTTP/1.1[0m" 404 -
[4/May/2022:06:48:55] 172.26.57.133 - - [04/May/2022 06:48:55] "[33mGET / HTTP/1.1[0m" 404 -
[4/May/2022:06:48:55] 172.26.7.217 - - [04/May/2022 06:48:55] "[33mGET / HTTP/1.1[0m" 404 -
[4/May/2022:06:48:55] 172.26.17.192 - - [04/May/2022 06:48:55] "[33mGET / HTTP/1.1[0m" 404 -
[4/May/2022:06:49:00] 172.26.47.225 - - [04/May/2022 06:49:00] "[33mGET / HTTP/1.1[0m" 404 -
[4/May/2022:06:49:00] 172.26.57.133 - - [04/May/2022 06:49:00] "[33mGET / HTTP/1.1[0m" 404 -
[4/May/2022:06:49:00] 172.26.7.217 - - [04/May/2022 06:49:00] "[33mGET / HTTP/1.1[0m" 404 -
[4/May/2022:06:49:00] 172.26.17.192 - - [04/May/2022 06:49:00] "[33mGET / HTTP/1.1[0m" 404 -
[4/May/2022:06:49:05] 172.26.47.225 - - [04/May/2022 06:49:05] "[33mGET / HTTP/1.1[0m" 404 -
[4/May/2022:06:49:05] 172.26.57.133 - - [04/May/2022 06:49:05] "[33mGET / HTTP/1.1[0m" 404 -
[4/May/2022:06:49:05] 172.26.7.217 - - [04/May/2022 06:49:05] "[33mGET / HTTP/1.1[0m" 404 -
[4/May/2022:06:49:05] 172.26.17.192 - - [04/May/2022 06:49:05] "[33mGET / HTTP/1.1[0m" 404 -
```

There's a few things confusing here to me:

1. I don't have the `/` specifically defined in my Flask application - is this necessary? It's clear the 404s are coming because the route is not defined, but I don't have any code from my React frontend that explicitly makes a request to this route. I'm not sure if I'm supposed to just create a `/` route on my Flask application that more or less does nothing
2. I see that the requests are coming in every 5 seconds - could this be some sort of health check? I'm certainly not visiting my frontend every 5 seconds. I do have Nginx set up on a Lightsail instance that's running my frontend and I'm not sure if that might have something to do with it

Any help is appreciated, thank you!